# How to use Protractor with chromeless

Tags: protractor, headless, chromeless

Is protractor compatible with chromeless? If so, how can I configure it?

I didn't find any configuration method online or specific documentation to implement chromeless at protractor configuration.

I'm using protractor 3.1.1

Comment: An upgrade on protractor selenium-webdriver is necessary, an issue was opened for it https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4427

Answer (score 0):

Chrome headless mode is available on Mac and Linux in Chrome 59. Windows support is in Chrome 60.

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName': process.env.PROTRACTOR_BROWSER || 'chrome',
    // Using headless Chrome
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ['--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--start-maximized']
    }
  }
```